# C#: Reading enums from text file

Tags: c#, enums, xna, stream

I'm making a 2D game with C# & XNA. I'm working on saving and loading currently, all of the data is stored in text files.

Each sprite has a state:

```
public enum SpriteState
{
    Alive,
    Dead,
    Chasing,
    Sleeping,
    Waiting 
}
```

When saving i'm simply executing this line of code:

```
StreamWriter.WriteLine(gameState);
```

Now when i'm loading a game i'm having to read that line of the text file store it in a string variable and perform near enough the following:

```
string inType = StreamReader.ReadLine();

if(inType == "Alive")
   //Set the sprites state to alive
else if(inType == "Dead")
   //Set the sprites state to alive
```

And so on... So my question is: Is there a better way of reading a enum type from a text file and assigning it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for

```
(SpriteState) Enum.Parse(typeof(SpriteState), inType)
```

This will parse a string into an enum value.

You may also want to have a `Dictionary<SpriteState, Action<...>>` mapping states to delegates (lambda expressions) that take the appropriate action.

Comment: That's brilliant,thankyou! didn't realise you could parse an enum - Will accept your answer when  time limit runs out!

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(SpriteState), yourString);
```

Also you can use this method:

```
public static T ParseEnum<T>(string value)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant,thankyou! didn't realise you could parse an enum - Will accept your answer when  time limit runs out!